# Is there a way to list all VM using typescript in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am trying to get the list of all VM from my azure resource group. I am using the armcompute as below.
Here I dont get the list of VM. and the length doesnot give me the proper count of VM's. I am not sure whether I am on the right path.

````
var computeClient = new armCompute.ComputeManagementClient(credentials, subscriptionId);       
const virtualMachines: any = computeClient.virtualMachines.list;
 console.log(`Found ${virtualMachines.length} virtual machines:`);```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way,

```
  msRestAzure.loginWithAppServiceMSI()
        .then(credentials => {
            computeClient = new computeManagementClient(credentials, subscriptionId);
            return computeClient.virtualMachines.listAll();
        })
        .then(vms => {
            done(context, 200, {vms: vms});
        })
        .catch(err => {
            doneWithError(context, err);
        });
```

[`SAMPLE CODE`](https://github.com/pulkitaggarwl/nodefunction/blob/2d1ece1a2f5c684d9362114d60954768b9e0ada0/get-running-vms/index.js)

Comment: I am very new to this. Can I do with spn? Like msest.loginwithserviceprincipal.  I am trying to create a build task in ADO. If I use computeclient =new computemanagementclient(credentials,subid) it throws an error like u need to write method for signin request.

Comment: you need to import a package

Comment: I have imported the package. The thing I am not understanding how to pass credential. I mean what's should be the format of credential?